ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED while installing any npm package
Getting this ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED error, every time I try to install any npm package.
I also installed this tls but I am still getting the same error
 npm install -g https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz

Error:

Node:
v20.14.0

Npm:
10.7.0

OS:
MacOS Monterey
version: 12.1

